# Erlang returns empty binary for aes encryption

Tags: encryption, erlang, aes

```
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Eshell V10.6.4  (abort with ^G)

1> application:ensure_all_started(crypto).
{ok,[crypto]}

2> Key = <<1:128>>.
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1>>

3> Text = <<"hello crypto">>.
<<"hello crypto">>

4> crypto:crypto_one_time(aes_128_ecb, Key, Text, true).
<<>>

5> Ref = crypto:crypto_init(aes_128_ecb, Key, true).
#Ref<0.3726173343.1880227841.208986>

6> crypto:crypto_update(Ref, Text).
<<>>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here but as you can see above, crypto_one_time and crypto_update both return an empty binary when I try to encrypt something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of use `crypto:crypto_one_time/5`:

```erlang
1> Key = <<1:128>>. 
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1>> 
2> IV = <<0:128>>. 
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0>> 
3> Txt = [<<"First bytes">>,<<"Second bytes">>]. 
[<<"First bytes">>,<<"Second bytes">>] 
4> crypto:crypto_one_time(aes_128_ctr, Key, IV, Txt, true).
<<67,44,216,166,25,130,203,5,66,6,162,16,79,94,115,234, 197,94,253,16,144,151,41>>
```

Example of use `crypto:crypto_one_time/4`:

```erlang
1> Key = <<1:128>>. 
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1>>
2> Txt = [<<"First bytes">>,<<"Second bytes">>].
[<<"First bytes">>,<<"Second bytes">>]
3> crypto:crypto_one_time(aes_128_ecb, Key,  Txt, true).   
<<231,108,83,104,188,131,182,65,2,128,78,162,210,149,128,248>>
```

Comment: This is really weird:
29> crypto:crypto_one_time(aes_128_ecb, <<1:128>>, [<<"hello crypto">>], true).       
<<>>

30> crypto:crypto_one_time(aes_128_ecb, <<1:128>>, [<<"first bytes">>], true). 
<<>>

31> crypto:crypto_one_time(aes_128_ecb, <<1:128>>, [<<"first bytessecond bytes">>], true).
<<190,194,121,123,212,150,123,4,103,37,23,215,133,255,150,
  80>>

Comment: Well this isn't very readable is it? So if I try [<<"hello crypto">>] or [<<"first bytes">>] it returns <<>> but when I use [<<"first bytessecond bytes">>] it returns the correct value

Comment: Does the text have to of be a certain length (byte size)?

Comment: The key has size 16 and the text must have size >= 16.